# How to differentiate $\sqrt[3]{x}$ by defintion

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Differentiate

$$
f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}
$$

By defintion.

I tried:

$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x+h}-\sqrt[3]{x}}{h}
$$

Multiplting by:

$$
\frac{\sqrt[3]{x+h}+\sqrt[3]{x}}{\sqrt[3]{x+h}+\sqrt[3]{x}}
$$

We get:

$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(x+h)^{2/3}-x^{2/3}}{h((x+h)^{1/3}+x^{1/3})}
$$

How can we proceed from here? (I prefer not using LHopital, cuz its just doing strait differentiation)

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: $(a - b)(a^2  + ab + b^2 ) = a^3  - b^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply the numerator and denominator by
$
(x+h)^{2/3}+x^{1/3}(x+h)^{1/3}+x^{2/3}
$
and use the factorization $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$
to deduce that
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x+h}-\sqrt[3]{x}}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h}{h((x+h)^{2/3}+x^{1/3}(x+h)^{1/3}+x^{2/3})}.
$$
You can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

$\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{x+h}-\sqrt[3]{x}}{h}=\dfrac{(\sqrt[3]{x+h}-\sqrt[3]{x})(\sqrt[3]{x+h}^2+\sqrt[3]{x+h}\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{x}^2)}{h(\sqrt[3]{x+h}^2+\sqrt[3]{x+h}\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{x}^2)}=\dfrac{h}{h(\sqrt[3]{x+h}^2+\sqrt[3]{x+h}\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{x}^2)}=\dfrac{1}{(\sqrt[3]{x+h}^2+\sqrt[3]{x+h}\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{x}^2)}$